# how to print the current screen with tkinter in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, printing

I use tkinter to build a GUI program, and now I want to print the current screen of the GUI to a paper or a pdf file. How can I do this please?
I know how to call the printer, but there are a lot of info in GUI, and the form of typesetting, do I need to write them all into the file? Or some simple way to do this please?

my environment: windows xp 32bit, python 3.4.4.

Comment: there are python modules which use external programs to create screenshot of full screen, any window or some region - ie. [pyscreenshot](https://github.com/ponty/pyscreenshot)